# Store directory path in C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I have to make a folder path reusable. When I open a folder the program must save it's directory one time so I can instantly reopen it when clicking the button without navigation in the folders.
I thought I create a string and store the path directory in it for a time.

How can I make this work?
I store the filepath in a textbox for now:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = @"D:\",
            Title = "Browse Text Files",

            CheckFileExists = true,
            CheckPathExists = true,

            DefaultExt = "txt",
            Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true,

            ReadOnlyChecked = true,
            ShowReadOnly = true
        };

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
```

Comment: yes but the folder path might change, depends what kind of txt/xml you open

Comment: It already works that way when you use RestoreDirectory = false.  Or don't assign InitialDirectory.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `static string` variable:

```
private const string initDefaultPath = @"D:\"; // <-- initial default folder path
private static string prevFolderPath = initDefaultPath;

//Let's suppose a button click event
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        InitialDirectory = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prevFolderPath)
            ? initDefaultPath
            : prevFolderPath,

        Title = "Browse Text Files",
        CheckFileExists = true,
        CheckPathExists = true,
        DefaultExt = "txt",
        Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
        FilterIndex = 2,
        RestoreDirectory = true,
        ReadOnlyChecked = true,
        ShowReadOnly = true
    };

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        prevFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: so when i want to open the same saved directory should I refer to prevFolderpath?

Comment: Exactly, that could be a solution. Be careful to always check if it is null, otherwise a NullReferenceException would be thrown

Comment: I've edited, by adding a `const string` where you can store your initial default path, so you can change it (if you need it) in one place.

Comment: This solution will not survive the application shutting down and starting again. Using a static mutable variable you have created a global variable that goes against a lot of the design principles of C#.

Comment: @JAlex Yes, I know that, but his request was not to survive an application reboot. I would be pleased to read any documentation you would like to send me, which attest that what I answered goes against any "principle". He asked a simple question about storing a string "life-runtime", I proposed a solution, you're still able to type down yours.

Comment: @NorbertBuchmuller - [a reference on static variables](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-make-global-variable-in-c-sharp) for you to read.

Comment: I only need it to remember while the application is running. I did it now it works. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @NorbertBuchmuller if this answer was helpful, please mark it as "correct" :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is for a way your form to remember for example the last used path. The official way of doing this to go to project properties and then into settings and add a new setting value of type string to store path or filename information.

[image: fig1]

Then you need two more things.

- Bind a textbox to the property for display purposes if needed. You do this manually in a `.NET Core` application by adding the following code into the `Form1.Designer.cs` file

  ```
  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
      ...
      this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(
          new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", 
          global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Settings.Default, 
          "lastPath", 
          true, 
          System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
      ...
  }
  ```

  Or if you are with `.NET Framework` then there is a UI option for the textbox under *ApplicationSettings*. [image: fig2]
- The last item you need for the form to save the settings when it is closing. This is done by handling the `FormClosing` event

  ```
   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
   }
  ```

Now your code can read and write to the textbox what it needs, and the settings file is going to kelp synchronized. For example in file opening operation, if you wish to store last lath in the textbox then do the following:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = textBox1.Text,
            Title = "Browse Text Files",

            CheckFileExists = true,
            CheckPathExists = true,

            DefaultExt = "txt",
            Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true,

            ReadOnlyChecked = true,
            ShowReadOnly = true
        };

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
```

This way each time the application is launched it remembers the contents of the text box

[image: fig3]

---

Note that the application will create a settings XML file in the following location:

[image: file]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Path.GetFullPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.1)

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Text = Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the path in a variable using what Jamiec said

then you would open the file a second time using system.io.open()

[link to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I will take a look at this

Comment: `system.io.open()` is definitely not a `.NET` framework/core thing. Are you talking about `System.IO.File.Open()` ?